# How I can define function to integrate lists using python?

Tags: python, function, nested-lists, named-entity-recognition

I am trying to define a function that iterates through three kind of list of lists, each list has the following structure:

```
sentiment_labels =  [['B_S', 'O', 'O', 'O'], ['O', 'O', 'B_S', 'O']]
aspect_labels =     [['O', 'B_A', 'O', 'O'], ['O', 'O', 'O', 'B_A']]
modifier_labels =   [['O', 'O', 'BM', 'O'], ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O']]

# those lists contain 'B_A', 'I_S', 'B_S', 'I_S', 'BM', 'IM', and 'O' labels (IOB Tagging)
```

the ***target result*** must be like:

```
labels = [['B_S', 'B_A', 'BM', 'O'], ['O', 'O', 'B_S', 'B_A'] ]
```

For this purpose, I have defined the following function:

```
# define function to integrate sentiments, aspects, and modifiers lists

def integrate_labels(sentiments_lists, aspects_lists, modifiers_lists):
  all_labels = []
  integrated_label = []

  # iterate through each list, then iterate through each element 
  for sentiment_list, aspect_list, modifier_list in zip(sentiments_lists, aspects_lists, modifiers_lists):
    
    for sentiment, aspect, modifier in zip(sentiment_list, aspect_list, modifier_list):

      # if the element is a sentiment label append it to the integrated_label list
      if sentiment != 'O':
        integrated_label.append(sentiment)

      # if the element is an aspect label append it to the integrated_label list
      elif aspect != 'O':
        integrated_label.append(aspect)

      # if the element is a modifier label append it to the integrated_label list
      elif modifier != 'O':
        integrated_label.append(modifier)

      else:
        integrated_label.append('O')
        
    # now append each integrated_label list to all_labels list
    all_labels.append(integrated_label)
  
  return all_labels
```

But I have this result:

```
integrate_labels(sentiment_labels, aspect_labels, modifier_labels)

[['B_S', 'B_A', 'BM', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'B_S', 'B_A'],
 ['B_S', 'B_A', 'BM', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'B_S', 'B_A']]
```

How I could change integrate_labels function to get the **target result** ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What if a position in several of those lists has a non-`'O'` value? Use the top one? The bottom one?

Comment: A position will get an Outside label 'O' if there is no other Beginning or Inside labels, i.e., B_A, I_A, B_S, I_S, BM, IM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change to

```
# now append each integrated_label list to all_labels list
all_labels.append(integrated_label.copy())
integrated_label = []
```